# How to build complex log structure using monolog?

Tags: php, logging, monolog

For every log event i have 'type' field. I want my log folder structure to be like:

```
Event_type (directory)
..Date (YY.MM.DD) (sub directory)
....Hour (HH) (sub directory)
......yy.mm.dd_hh.mm.ss_event_type.log (log file)
```

Is it possible to do log folder structure like that using monolog?

Comment: You want a different log file for every second of the day?

Comment: Every hour of the day

Comment: Your naming scheme shows the log file name changing for every minute and second as well.